# How to hide a folder for a certain user in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am administrator in my Windows 7 PC.

How can I make an installed program invisible for a certain user (in the Program Files folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´d recommend changing NTFS permissions. Right click on folder, then Security. That way you can  restrict visibility for the folder AND disallow opening it or running anything in it , or whatever. Infact, you can go into more detail than you´ll probably ever need in a home PC.

Some background on NTFS permissions [here](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html).

Comment: I haven't seen an option to change the *visibility for the folder*. You can only deny the read permission, but the folder is still visible.

Comment: The "List folder"-permission grants/denies visibility.

Comment: I have only a *List Folder Contents* option on my Win10 machine. Perhaps *List folder* is only for Active Directory?

Comment: @JannisAlexakis hello I tried this, and it only works like denying other people to list the folder, is there anyway to hide the folder from listing? Like example \\Users\Foo, and the user login as Anonymous logon or guest, the \\users\foo still shown. I don't know why it's shown, as it shouldn't by default. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the user you want to hide folder from is not very familiar with computers.

Then you could:
  1. right click on folder, and choose hidden. close that window.

2. Go to control panel, and to folder options. Find and turn on option to hide hidden folders.
3. From that users start menu right click on shortcut and delete so they do not see it there 
   either.

(This should be done from the users account, not You/Admin)

Here is some more info on password protecting folders and files.

http://ws-technologies.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hide-your-secrets-password-lock-folder-windows-7-with-no-additional-software-0133578/